# Node js hangs up on port 3000 I have to restart PC to unblock it

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemon

So for past few weeks I have an enormous problem with node on our windows server 2006.

Basically since I installed an update for nodemon using

```
npm install -g nodemon
```

Our node started to hang up on our port (default 3000) and the process hangs on Windows. I've tried every possible solution from the web to kill that process and I simply can't -- the only way to unblock the port is to restart whole server.

The port hangs mostly when I want to restart node to implement the changes or when I want to turn it off.

It's not *always* happening -- mostly it happens after it's been running for 30+ minutes.

My node version is 6.10.0.

Before I updated nodemon something like this never happened before.

And yes, I uninstalled nodemon completely using

```
npm uninstall -g nodemon
```

Can anyone guide me to a solution?

Comment: Your NodeJS version is only 6.10? Try updating it :)

Comment: Maybe try reinstalling node and npm

Comment: if you are running node with nodemon you shouldn't have to restart your node server to implement changes? That is what nodemon does? You will need to post a bit of code

Comment: @WebD Did you see the Windows version? Not sure the place is keeping up to date with anything :).

Comment: Try to capture memory dump on windows server 2006. It will give all the details about all the processes running at the time when your machine hang up. May be it’s not nodemon.

Comment: What about switching to a different port?

Comment: yea I can switch to different port, but it will hang up later and ill have to switch again and most programs operate on our default one..

I will update node and will let you know